# List every git command I have ever made

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to list every git command I have ever ran from a particular repository?

`git log` for example just shows all the commits. And not even just my commits, but everyones for that repo.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with Git.

With GitHub API, you could [list events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events) (even the [events performed by a user)](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user) and see if you can get at least pushes from users.

If you were to push a repo on a Git repo hosting server that you control, you could install an authorization layer that **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview.html)** which does have an [audit log](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#lff) allowing you to parse and extract git commands from a specific user.